# Creating stacked area plot and coloring from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to create a stacked area plot in any python plotting library where each row is the data, and the last column "color" dictates the color of the that specific rows area plot. I want to group the various colors together on the same plot, and give them a slight white border. I have attached a image that represents almost identically the plot I am trying to make.

Thank you.

My dataframe:
P0_normalized  G1_normalized  G2_normalized  G3_normalized  G4_normalized  
0        0.135595       0.223092       0.150101       0.059581       0.041935
1        0.079456       0.089304       0.060875       0.013410       0.009746
2        0.078227       0.090398       0.057821       0.013292       0.006697
3        0.077279       0.090198       0.067936       0.020701       0.014716
4        0.063746       0.061763       0.042486       0.009376       0.007951
5        0.060371       0.061896       0.043301       0.016992       0.009096
6        0.056730       0.052527       0.040298       0.011697       0.005877
7        0.052747       0.047035       0.032997       0.008430       0.004426
8        0.052741       0.056978       0.037971       0.010379       0.008119
9        0.044449       0.050925       0.034073       0.011151       0.010792
10       0.038630       0.028947       0.020418       0.006750       0.005565
11       0.037348       0.035704       0.026198       0.007701       0.006900
12       0.032034       0.009996       0.073353       0.179985       0.194423
13       0.029499       0.023580       0.017262       0.005437       0.003773
14       0.027906       0.009315       0.066169       0.150548       0.167291
15       0.022392       0.005870       0.045097       0.108797       0.113040
16       0.020817       0.021813       0.015226       0.002914       0.004831
17       0.020294       0.004860       0.031645       0.074930       0.083654
18       0.018762       0.019659       0.014172       0.004669       0.003246
19       0.018172       0.007575       0.058098       0.139034       0.143308
20       0.016750       0.004691       0.033579       0.072892       0.075210
21       0.016056       0.003872       0.030925       0.071334       0.079405

```
G5_normalized color
```

0        0.020739     b
1        0.004965     b
2        0.002613     b
3        0.006816     b
4        0.003396     b
5        0.003891     b
6        0.002221     b
7        0.001829     b
8        0.003417     b
9        0.015881     b
10       0.002857     b
11       0.002879     b
12       0.204991     r
13       0.001569     b
14       0.181939     r
15       0.123564     r
16       0.008557     b
17       0.086668     r
18       0.001771     b
19       0.157914     r
20       0.079980     r
21       0.081541     r

[image]

Thank you for any assistance you may have.

I tried to filter the dataframe by color as following:

new_df_b = new_df[new_df['color'] == 'b']

new_df_r = new_df[new_df['color'] == 'r']

I then created new dataframes to remove the color column

new_df_b=new_df_b[["P0_normalized", "G1_normalized", "G2_normalized", "G3_normalized", "G4_normalized", "G5_normalized"]]

new_df_r=new_df_r[["P0_normalized", "G1_normalized", "G2_normalized", "G3_normalized", "G4_normalized", "G5_normalized"]]

I then tried to plot them transposed separately as follows:

new_df_b.T.plot.area(color='blue')

new_df_r.T.plot.area(color='red')

However, I cannot get them to plot on the same plot. it always make them separate.